# How to test scale constraint in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, constraints

In Grails domain class i have Field

```
BigDecimal grossWeight
```

and constraint for it

```
static constraints = {
      grossWeight(nullable: true, min: BigDecimal.ZERO, scale: 3)
   }
```

I like to have test for scale constraint but don't know how to implement it

Following not works

```
formxItem = new FormXItem(grossWeight: new BigDecimal("0.1234"))
assert !formxItem.validate()
assertNotNull formxItem.errors['grossWeight']
```

Comment: did you use mockForConstraintTests !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [scale](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/scale.html), the constraint does not register any validation errors, so it will not fail validation.  Instead it sets the column's precision in the database and automatically scales down the precision of the number, if necessary.